# print out a group of values from a procedure into one table on SQL server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I need to print out a group of values from a procedure on SQL server 2008.

If I use select , it generated a distinct table into the result part of SQL server 2008 managemetn studio every time the procedure  is called.

i need to call the procedure in a loop. I want to print the values into one table.

Thx!

```
 while
 begin
        my_procedure()
 end 


  my_procedure()
    # do something
    select value1, value2, value3
```

i need to keep the

```
   value1, value2, value3
```

in one single table after the loop is done.

Currently, everytime my_procedure() is called, a new table is created in SQL server MS.

I want to keep all of them in one single table.

Comment: can you post an example of what you are trying to do?

Comment: Having you tried the `print` command?  (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx)

Comment: @Gordon Linoff , I need to save them into a table. thx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
INSERT INTO #tempTable (Col1, col2, .....)
EXEC TestSP
```

Check this link as well:
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/09/23/sql-server-insert-values-of-stored-procedure-in-table-use-table-valued-function/

Comment: @thin Gangadharan, the tempyable will be gone after it returns from the procedure. Next time, a new tempyable will be created again ? right ?

Comment: @thin Gangadharan,  what is "TestSP" ?

Comment: TestSP is the stored proc name, so you have to replace it with your SP name. Scope of the #TempTable is the current session, so it will work as per your requirement.

Comment: @thin Gangadharan, I need to pass in "#tempTable" as an argument to TestSP ? my_procudere is in another file. If I put INSERT INTO #tempTable before ther defination of my_procudere , these is an error.

Comment: What's the error?..please make sure no. of columns and datatype should same SP's output and temp table should match.